# Do I lose values of vertical asymptote if I express a rational function in lowest term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3 -1}{x - x^2}$$
Is the function in question.
If I factor out the denominator as $x(1-x)$, then, after another step, I end up with $y=0$ being the only Vertical Asymptote, and my
Casio CG10 calculator shows that. However, when I try to calculate the value of the function for $x=1$, the machine gives error. But the graph itself does not show that! On the screen for the graph, there is no restriction for $x=1$. So, what am I missing here? This is NOT a homework problem, I am refreshing some concepts.

Comment: No calculator error. But when a calculator draws a smooth graph it can only sample some finite number of points, then it just connects them up with tiny line segments. So the calculator typically misses removable singularities.

Comment: In other words, there is no asymptote at $x=1$ because even though the function is not defined there it does approach a finite limit. Here's a simpler example: consider the function $f(x)={x\over x}$.

Comment: You meant to write that the only vertical asymptote is $x = 0$.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig, yes, that's what I meant. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

An asymptote only exists where the limit at a point does not approach a finite value, so no asymptote is lost. However, in your original function there is a hole precisely at $x=1$ that no longer exists when you reduce the fraction

A simpler example of this is $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ which has a hole at $0$, yet it simplifies to $f(x)=1$ which does not